# Write audio.amr into byte Array

Tags: java

I have some problem with my android app. I need to convert existing audio file into byte array.  My audio file is in `/sdcard/SomeFolder/111.amr`

```
    try {
        convert();
    }catch (IOException e){
        RLog.log(LogLevel.HIGH, "MyApp", "Audio File not found");
    }
```

Convert method is looking like this

```
public void convert() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "SomeFolder/111.amr");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];

    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/recording.pcm");
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
}
```

But when i'm trying to use method `convert()` i'm getting `FileNotFoundExeption - "Audio File not found"`

Can you please help me. What is wrong with path?

Comment: I guess serialization is needed here but error says file not found check fileinputstream line.. Something wrong there

Comment: ` Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "SomeFolder/111.amr"` 
Is this a good code if file is in MyDevice ->SomeFolder->111.amr ?

Comment: allow user to choose it.. Anyways you are going to do so

Comment: You could try to print out the value of the expression `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "SomeFolder/111.amr"` and make sure it's a valid file. Also you might want to specify from which library the `Environment` class is. Chances are that that `getPath()` returns a value that does not end with a `/`.